# Undeclared variable in JS automatically picking up DOM objects

Tags: javascript, html, browser

Look at the following JS code:

```
alert(myImgId.src);
```

and corresponding HTML:

```
<img id="myImgId" src="http://images4.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20121128141533/logopedia/images/6/6f/Superman_logo.png"></img>
```

What I expect would happen:
A javascript error specifying that it cannot find variable `myImgId` , basically a sort of NPE while accessing object `src` of `myImgId`.

What actually happens:
Modern browsers(FF 17 & above, chrome) pick up the DOM element with the given ID automatically.
Older versions of browsers like FF 10 throw an error as expected.

Can somebody explain what is happening over here?

[JSFiddle link](http://jsfiddle.net/divijvaidya13/AxV9R/)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Automatically created variables from ids in JS?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114956/automatically-created-variables-from-ids-in-js)

Comment: Oow, i did know this was possible. I tested in opera, chrome, ie(9,10, dont have 8 atm) and worked perfectly.

Comment: It's in the HTML5 standard - see http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#named-access-on-the-window-object

Answer (score 2):

I gleaned this from another SO question, the question is not really the same as your question, but the answer does answer your question:

[Can I Use an ID as a Variable Name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6852883/can-i-use-an-id-as-a-variable-name)

and here is the good stuff: (all quoted from Sidnicious' answer)

> Making global variables automatically is considered bad practice
>   because it can be difficult to tell, looking at some code, whether it
>   is on purpose or you forgot to declare a variable somewhere. Automatic
>   creation of global variables like this doesn’t work in ES5 strict mode
>   and could be phased out phased out in future versions of ECMAScript.
>
> In the browser JavaScript’s global scope is actually window. When you
>   refer to document you get window.document. Best practice for creating
>   a global variable in a browser is to add it to window (global in
>   Node.js)....
>
> ...It turns out that most browsers create properties on window (hence
>   global variables) for each id in the document. Many browsers don’t
>   make them read-only, you can overwrite them with your own, but
>   Internet Explorer does.
>
> This is another reason global variables in JavaScript can be dangerous
>   — one of your ids could match a read-only window property (today or in
>   some future browser).

Comment: this should be a comment, not just a copy and paste of the other guy's answer (even though it is credited)

Answer (score -1):

My guess is:

Since you did not declare the variable with `var`, it is seen as a global variable (global to the entire window) and the browser is automatically hooking it up, since the ID is the same as the object name.

Comment: don't just guess - _obviously_ the ID is being automatically added to `window`.  What the OP needs is a reference to this in the DOM spec.

Comment: and here it is - http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/#named-access-on-the-window-object