# Javascript variable has been assigned, but I cannot find where

Tags: javascript, dom

I'm working with some javascript (about 12,000 lines of it) and there is a few instances of this

```
if (!chkLoad.checked) {
```

But when I do a search for *chkLoad* I cannot find it declared of assigned anywhere. I even searched multiple files from the root of the project and even though it finds 50 instances of chkLoad it does not find anything like

```
var chkLoad = document.getElementById('chkLoad');
```

When I debug the site in Firebug, when I break on one of the conditionals, it does show that *chkLoad* is in fact the element with **ID** of *chkLoad*, but no where in the code shows the assignment of *chkLoad*.

What might I be missing with my search to find where *chkLoad* is defined and then assigned?

Comment: Is it one single 12000 line file? Look in your HTML, maybe it's declared there.

Comment: Only html is <input id="chkLoad" value="" /> - That wouldnt assign it the js variable of chkLoad though?

Comment: Some browsers, I think, *do* automatically create globals based on the `id` of elements, as mentioned here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114956/automatically-created-variables-from-ids-in-js and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5515659/javascript-variable-corresponds-to-dom-element-with-the-same-id

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Javascript, you can refer to an HTML element by it's ID.

HTML:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="chkLoad">
```

JS:

```
alert(chkLoad.checked)
```

Here is the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/qC76e/

Apologies that you've inherited 12,000 lines of JS.

Comment: Learned something new thanks!