# Why am I getting [object HTML ParagraphElement] Returned instead of my number

Tags: javascript, html

I have a silly fiddle that I am stuck with, I am trying to take the beginning number and double it every time the x2 button is hit. Instead of this behavior I am getting [object HTML ParagraphElement] returned instead. I am re-learning JavaScript so I am trying to work with just JavaScript, no frameworks etc...

```js
var inputVal = document.getElementById("input").value;
var inputEl = document.getElementById("input");
var doubleButton = function () {
  var sum = 0;
  Number(input);
  sum = input + input;
  inputEl.value = input;
  inputEl.innerText = input;
}
var boom = function () {
  alert("BOOM!!!!! Dont you know you should never press the big red  button")
}
document.getElementById("btnAdd").addEventListener("click", doubleButton, false);
document.getElementById("btnRed").addEventListener("click", boom, false);
```

```html
<p>Enter a number and click the x2 button to have it doubled</p>
<p id="input">5</p>
<br>
<button id="btnAdd">x2</button>
<br>
<button class="redBtn" id="btnRed">BIG RED BUTTON</button>
```

here is the link to my actual fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/jpb4815/uynfc1ky/16/

Why is my code returning object and not the number, I thought that I had taken care of that with the number function by converting the input from a string to a number. I have tried a variety of different settings in fiddler the onload, no wrap in body. I have changed the code a multitude of times. I could do it in jQuery but I really want just plain vanilla JavaScript.

Comment: You get the input element and store it in `inputVal`, but you use `input` later. `input` is the actual DOM element, hence why you're getting it.

Comment: Note `innerText` is not standard and won't work on Firefox. Better use `textContent`.

Comment: Maybe this is what you want: http://jsfiddle.net/BloodyKnuckles/uynfc1ky/22/

Comment: @bloody knuckles that puts me on the right tract thank you, but I need to keep incrementing  each time the button is clicked, so always double the number. I think that I need to update my function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First your `input` variable is not instantiated. I'm surprised that passed muster. [Here's a bit on that.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7114956/automatically-created-variables-from-ids-in-js)

So, where to get the initial value? Since a `p` tag doesn't have a `value` property, I'm pulling the `p` tag id'd as `input`, retrieving the `innerHTML` property, and running the result through `parseInt`.

Also, pull `document.getElementById` into your function so the button will have what it needs each time it's called.

And finally, `sum` was summed but not assigned to your output.

[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/BloodyKnuckles/uynfc1ky/22/)

```
(function () {
    var doubleButton = function () {
        var inputEl = document.getElementById("input");
        var inputVal = inputEl.innerHTML;
        var input = parseInt(inputVal, 10);
        var sum = input + input;
        inputEl.innerText = sum;

    }
    var boom = function () {
        alert("BOOM!!!!! Dont you know you should never press the big red button")
    }
    document.getElementById("btnAdd").addEventListener("click", doubleButton, false);
    document.getElementById("btnRed").addEventListener("click", boom, false);
}());
```

Comment: thanks for explaining why my solution was not working, I need tho think more my mark up.

Answer (score 1):

Try  this:

```
(function () {
            var inputEl = document.getElementById("input");
            var doubleButton = function () {
                var sum = 0;
                input = Number(inputEl.textContent);
                sum = input + input;
                inputEl.textContent = sum;

            }
            var boom = function () {
                alert("BOOM!!!!! Dont you know you should never press the big red  button")
            }
            document.getElementById("btnAdd").addEventListener("click", doubleButton, false);
            document.getElementById("btnRed").addEventListener("click", boom, false);

        }());
```